# Cairo overriding font selection in R graphics?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I have been using `Cairo::CairoPNG` to export graphics for a while now, on Windows 10. Recently (I'm fairly certain this didn't used to happen), Cairo has started ignoring any font family selection in my graphics.

Here is a minimal example with a **ggplot2** graph, although I find the same thing happens with base-R plots:

```r
library(Cairo)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
```

This looks as expected:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + theme(text = element_text(family = 'serif'))
```

[image: ggplot graph with serif font]

Whereas this reverts to some font I can't quite identify (I'm pretty sure it's not `ggplot`-default Arial)

```r
Cairo(file = 'plot.png')
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + theme(text = element_text(family = 'serif'))
dev.off()
```

[image: ggplot graph produced by Cairo with sans-serif font]

The same problem occurs if I use `dev = 'CairoPNG'` in RMarkdown/**bookdown**, which is actually how I noticed the problem in the first place (and is what makes me certain it's a new problem - I've been re-building the same book in **bookdown** for a while and this didn't used to be a problem). Despite this being new, reverting from the current 1.5-15 version of **Cairo** to 1.5-14 didn't fix anything.

Is there something I can do to fix this? I do like those high-res graphics!

Comment: have you tried a ragg device? https://cran.r-project.org/package=ragg

Comment: Hmm, ragg does not seem to have the same problem (although at least by its defaults the output quality seems lower than the default R png device)

Comment: maybe increase the resolution then ? :)

Comment: Seems reasonable